# file attachment option in accordions

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I am trying to give file attachment option in accordions.
accordions we can consider a type of button which we can collapse and expand.

[Click here for Accordion reference that I am using](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/accordion/overview/#nbaccordioncomponent)

I am designing accordions according to the JSON data that is coming from the web services.
Suppose I have total 3 headers in JSON data then using `ngFor` it will make 3 accordions.

The problem I am facing that whenever I am attaching any document in the accordions, it's file name going to showing on the first accordions but it should show on the accordion in which I am adding a file or document.

I wrote a code to show the filenames in the typescript.

**Sample.component.html file is as follows:**

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl" class="accordions-container row">
         <div class="accordion-container col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xxxl-12">
            <nb-accordion multi >
               <nb-accordion-item *ngFor="let Data of SampleData;index as i" [attr.data-index]="i" #items1 >
               <nb-accordion-item-header id="{{Data.key}}" class="row" style="margin-right: 0px;">
                  <div class="col-lg-10"><b>{{Data.HeaderName}}</b></div>
               </nb-accordion-item-header>
               <nb-accordion-item-body>
                  <div>
                     <ul>

                     <!-- here I am uploading the files-->
                        <div class="uploadfiles">
                           <div class="col-lg-2">
                              <div class="image-upload" id="{{Data.key}}">
                                 <label for="file-input">
                                 </label>
                                 <input id="file-input" type="file" multiple="multiple" (change)="uploadFiles($event,Data.Post,'filename',Data.key);salert(Data.key)"/>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     </ul>

                  </div>
                  <!-- Here I am printing the files -->
                  <div *ngFor="let file of Data.Post.files">
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                           <div class="image-dlt">
                              <li id="{{file.name}}">{{file.name}}</li>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </nb-accordion-item-body>
               </nb-accordion-item>
            </nb-accordion>
            </div>
            </div>
```

**sample.componet.ts file**

```
 files: Object = [];
    uploadFiles(e: Event, Post, file, key) {
        var target: HTMLInputElement = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
        Post.files = target.files;

    }
```

If I expand the second accordion and attach any file. then it is going to show in the first accordion. but I wanted to show the attached file just after the attached button in particular accordion.

I already did a lot of R&D on this but till now couldn't able to solve my problem.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you add codes or screenshots to show examples?

Comment: Please show us the code that's involved, or at least a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Comment: @SebaCherian Not images. The point is that we should be able to, easily, run the code ourselves. One of the off-topic close votes available is that images was used (or rather, that the code should be in the question itself - which is isn't if it's in an image that can dissapear at any time).

Comment: @SebaCherian@fredrik Please see the updated post. Also, the accordions that I am using as a reference. here is the link.

https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/accordion/overview/#nbaccordioncomponent